# What's the meaning of assigning one variable with 2 values in Java

Tags: java

I am new in Java, I saw this code today and don't get what it means. It is assigning a variable with 2 values, so what is the value of this variable 'actual'?

```
Token actual=new Token(MODULE, 0, 0, ""), expected;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base syntax of a variable declaration is actually:

```
<type> <name> [ = <value> ] [ , <name> [ = <value> ] ]...
```

E.g. these are all valid:

```java
int x;             // declares x, leaving it unassigned
int x = 5;         // declares x, initializing it
int x, y;          // declares x and y, leaving both unassigned
int x = 5, y = 7;  // declares x and y, initializing both
int x, y = 7;      // declares x and y, initializing y, leaving x unassigned
int x = 5, y;      // declares x and y, initializing x, leaving y unassigned
```

The code in the question declares 2 variables named `actual` and `expected`, initializes `actual`, and leaves `expected` unassigned.

Answer (score 4):

It creates two variables: `actual`, which is assigned `new Token(MODULE, 0, 0, "")`; and `expected`, which is left unassigned.